# setting up cakephp acl database

Tags: php, cakephp, acl, cakephp-2.4

I'm trying to set up CakePHP's acl feature, for a bit of experimentation. The documentation says I can do:

```
Console\cake acl initdb
```

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/acl-shell.html

Or perhaps:

```
cake schema create DbAcl
```

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/access-control-lists.html#defining-permissions-cakephp-s-database-acl

However they return the same error:

```
The chosen schema could not be loaded. Attempted to load:
File: C:\wamp\www\cakeuser\app\Config\Schema\schema.php
Name: DbAcl
```

I ran these commands from the `/app` folder.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Q: "What am I doing wrong?"  A: using ACL in the first place  (IMO of course)

Comment: Oh ok... tbh i'm just checking out various frameworks and getting to grips with the features they offer

Comment: ACL *might* have it's uses, but is overly-complicated IMO.  Unless you need every feature it offers and EXACTLY those, there are much easier ways to go.  CakePHP is amazing, and I back it 100%, but - passing along the knowledge I received when trying to use it myself "Unless you KNOW you NEED ACL, then you don't need ACL."  (I realize this doesn't answer your question though)

Comment: Fair play then. I quite like cakephp so far so will check out some other areas instead. I was looking at ACL because of this plugin http://milesj.me/code/cakephp/admin

Comment: @Dave I agree it is over-complicated. I've also used Croogo the cake cms, it made my app very slow. Do you have any alternate solution to implement Access Control layer in cake app ?

Comment: @MoyedAnsari - the only "answer" I have is that once you get the hang of CakePHP, you can manage your users and user-access in whatever way best suites YOUR needs.  Eg. Do you just need to restrict access to 'admin_' methods?  Or do you want to store access per controller::action? ...etc etc etc.

Comment: i want to give access as per controller/action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you can manually run the db_acl.sql in mysql file located in app/Config/Schema/.

Comment: After doing that and running `Console\cake admin.install` I get an error: `Shell class InstallShell could not be found.`.

Comment: did you install the plugin using Composer ?

Answer (score 1):

For me work execute the code linke this: 
`c:\wamp\www\cake\app>cake schema create dbAcl`
instead of this 
`c:\wamp\www\cake\app>cake schema create DbAcl`

look the dbAcl in my case must to be in lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

you should run cake schema create DbAcl from the app path not from the console folder.